# Show only max values in d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following bar chart.

https://jsfiddle.net/zyjp1abo/

As you can see the values are between 1000 and 1005. Showing all the data from 0 to 1005 does not sense since the differences aren't visible.

I'd like to show the bars from 1000 and 1005 and change the y axis accordingly. Simply using `extent` and changing the domain does not work since the bars are drawn through the bottom margin. I want them to stop at the lowest value, i.e 1000.

https://jsfiddle.net/zyjp1abo/1/

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the domain to go from 1000 to 1005, you should use `d3.extent`. That's not the problem.

The problem is that you are using `d3.extent` but you keep using `y(0)` both for translating your x axis and for calculating the bars heights, which is wrong. You have to use your `height` and your margins.

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var defaults = {
  target: '#chart',
  width: 500,
  height: 170,
  margin: {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  },
  yTicks: 5
}

class Barchart {
  constructor(config) {
    Object.assign(this, defaults, config)

    const {
      target,
      width,
      height,
      margin
    } = this
    const w = width - margin.left - margin.right
    const h = height - margin.top - margin.bottom

    const {
      yTicks
    } = this

    this.chart = d3.select(target)
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)

    this.x = d3.scaleBand()
      .rangeRound([0, w])
      .padding(0.1)

    this.y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([h, 0])

    this.xAxis = d3.axisBottom(this.x)

    this.chart.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'x axis')

    this.yAxis = d3.axisLeft(this.y)
      .ticks(yTicks)

    this.chart.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'y axis')
  }

  render(data) {
    const {
      x,
      y,
      xAxis,
      yAxis,
      chart
    } = this

    // y.domain(d3.extent(data, v => v.value))
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, v => v.value))

    const domain = data.map(d => d.timestamp)
    x.domain(domain)

    chart.select('.x.axis')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${(defaults.height - defaults.margin.bottom - defaults.margin.top)})`)
      .call(xAxis)

    chart.select('.y.axis')
      .call(yAxis)

    const bars = chart.selectAll('.bar')
      .data(data)

    bars
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'bar')
      .merge(bars)
      .attr('x', d => x(d.timestamp))
      .attr('y', d => y(d.value))
      .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
      .attr('height', d => defaults.height - defaults.margin.bottom - defaults.margin.top - y(d.value))
  }

}

const random = (min = -10, max = 10) => (
  window.Math.floor(window.Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
)

let bar = []
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  bar.push({
    timestamp: Date.now() - (19 - i) * 500,
    value: random(1000, 1005)
  })
}

const barchart = new Barchart()
barchart.render(bar)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg id="chart">
</svg>
```

PS: You could simplify the math for the SVG size and margins.

PPS: There is a lot of debate regarding if a dataviz can have a non-zero baseline. I believe that some kinds of charts, in some situations, can and should have a non-zero baseline, specially line charts, when the change rate is more important than the absolute value, for instance. However, bar charts should **always** have a zero baseline.

Answer (score 1):

After you change your domain, this line:

```
 .attr('height', d => Math.abs(y(d.value) - y(0)))
```

Is still calculating the height of the bar based of a `0` value.  The conventional way to calculate the height as in [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304), is to base it off the inner height of your chart (your variable `h`).

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyjp1abo/2/).

Answer (score 0):

`y.domain([0, d3.max(data, v => v.value)])`

change `0` here to `1000`, and other places respectively